# AG Grid paste: asynchronous processCellFromClipboard

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

When pasting text into a cell in AgGrid, I need to both validate and rewrite the value (change from text to an ID). My problem is that this has to happen asynchronously, since it is impractical to load all acceptable values on the client.

Here is what I have tried:

1. [processCellFromClipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/clipboard/#processing-individual-cells) would be the ideal place to handle this, but it seems it cannot be used asynchronously - it needs to return the transformed value immediately.
2. Handling it in the [valueSetter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-setters/#value-setter), but valueSetter should return a boolean indicating whether the cell was changed or not - which is not possible until the async call is complete.
3. [processDataFromClipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/clipboard/#processing-data-from-clipboard) - basically handle entire paste yourself. But this seems very inconvenient, since we cannot return the transformed data from the function, but are instead forced to return null and manually update every cell. Is there an API call available to "manually" apply paste data to the current grid?

Is either of these approaches possible, or is there another approach? Note that I still would like things like cellValueChanged to be fired, and cellFlash to work as before.

I'm using the React flavor of the Ag Grid, if that makes any difference.